# How to factorise this expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Factorise the following expression:
$$x^2+x(a+b)-2ab$$

---

I have just learned to factorise expressions. And I was taking some expressions of my own. And I found an expression which I was unable to factorise (it's on top). Would anyone please help me out

Answer (score 2):

You have chosen an example that is not easy to factorize.

By using the quadratic formula which states that the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ is $\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

The roots are

$$x_1 = \frac{-(a+b) - \sqrt{(a+b)^2+8ab}}{2}, x_2 = \frac{-(a+b) + \sqrt{(a+b)^2+8ab}}{2}$$

Since the leading coefficient is $1$, the factorization is

$$(x - x_1) (x-x_2)$$

Comment: Siong Thye Goh the answer you have provided, I guess is only when equation is 0.

Comment: Anyway thank you for considering my question

Comment: @boraramireddy No. When you are to factorize, you should find the roots of the given expression $P(x)$. For this, you solve $P(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

For a quadratic expression given as $$rx^2 + px + q$$ whose roots are, say, $m$ and $n$, it can be factorised as $$rx^2 + px + q = r(x-m)(x-n)$$

So now, you should find the solutions to your equation. Ask if you cannot.

Comment: VIVID thank you a lot